# Unable to perform onPress in ReactNative nested component

Tags: react-native

So I am using react native and an unable to get the function to be called onPress. I have a SearchUser component which has a render method within which I have called

```
<ShowUsers allUsers={this.state.details} access_token={this.state.access_token}/>
```

Now the ShowUsers is as follows

```
class ShowUsers extends Component{ 
....
render(){
var user = this.state.details;
var userList = user.map(function(user,index){
      var img={
        uri:user.avatar.uri,
      }
      return(
        <ListItem icon  key={ index }>
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail small source={img} />
              </Left>
              <Body>
              <Text>{"@"+user.uname+" "+user.id}</Text>
                <Text note>{user.fname+" "+user.lname}</Text>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                  <Icon style={{fontSize:30}} name="ios-add-circle" onPress={this.followThem(user.id).bind(this)} />
              </Right>
          </ListItem>
        );
      });
      return(
        <View>
         {userList}
       </View>);
    }

followThem(userId){
  Alert.alert("userId "+userId);
 }
```

When I click the icon I get the following errror 
undefined is not a function (evaluating this.followThem(user.id))

As far as I understand the value of this is undefined however I have used functions such as the one below in my SearchUser component. Which calls the function properly

```
 <Icon onPress={this.goBack.bind(this)} name="arrow-back" />
```

I have also tried this.followThem.bind(this,user.id) but to no avail what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified answer -

```
  render() {
    var user = [11,22,33];
    var userList = user.map((u,i) => {
      return(
        <Text key={i} onPress={this.followThem.bind(this, u)}>{u}</Text>
      );
    });
    .....
  }
```

Notice the arrow function used in `map`. It automatically binds `this` to callback.

You can also do -

```
<Text key={i} onPress={() => this.followThem(u)}>{u}</Text>
```